# VB.NET - how to remove Infragistics references

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I moved a vb project to a new computer. This one does not have Infragistics libraries installed. Apparently on the original computer it was installed, and the vb project must have some reference to it (see error bellow) even though I'm not using it in the project. So I am getting this error on the new computer.

Unable to resolve type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo, Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v9.1, Version=9.1.20091.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the list of "references" for the project, if there is a reference in there (probably with a yellow warning shield) then simply delete it. After that look in the vbproj file for any other references. That should address it.

If it is not in either of those two areas, look for imports in the source files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all refrences of the Infragistics components. You need to remove from Refrences folder, by doing this you have to remove all the code refering to the controls using those refrences. You need to use predefined controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the add or remove program in control panel. using that you can uninstall the this components.

Comment: I think they meant remove the references from the project

Comment: I'm talking about removing it from Visual Studio 2008, not from the PC where it is not installed infact